# Database deadlock after spock test execuction

Tags: postgresql, spock, dbunit

I try to write dbunit test in spock, so I configured datasource to postgres database:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        PGSimpleDataSource source = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        source.setServerName(environment.getProperty("db.test.server.name"));
        source.setDatabaseName(environment.getProperty("db.test.database.name"));
        source.setUser(environment.getProperty("db.test.user.name"));
        source.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.test.user.password"));

        return source;
    }
```

I have two methods. The @After one:

```
def setup() {
        tester = new DataSourceDatabaseTester(dataSource)
        tester.setSchema("schema")
        tester.setSetUpOperation(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
        tester.setTearDownOperation(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
    }
```

and before one:

```
def cleanup() {
        tester.onTearDown();
    }
```

In my test groovy script I have set transactional

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
class SimpleDaoTest extends CommonTestSetup{
```

defined dataset:

```
 def data =dataSet {
        //simple data
    };
```

and given test

```
@Test
@Rollback
void test(){
    //update operation
    //select operation
    //some check
}
```

Problem is that after test execution there is some deadlock on postgres database and test has never finished. Probably the code line tester.onTearDown(); stops on mentioned deadlock. To check it I  executed query

```
SELECT bl.pid     AS blocked_pid,
         a.usename  AS blocked_user,
         kl.pid     AS blocking_pid,
         ka.usename AS blocking_user,
         a.query    AS blocked_statement
   FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         bl
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity a  ON a.pid = bl.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         kl ON kl.transactionid = bl.transactionid AND kl.pid != bl.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity ka ON ka.pid = kl.pid
   WHERE NOT bl.granted;
```

which returned:

blocked_pid;blocked_user;blocking_pid;blocking_user,blocked_statement
13387;"postgres";13385;"postgres";"insufficient privilege"

Can anybody help me what I am doing wrong, and what causes mentioned deadlock?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that update or delete on database start new transaction, and before transaction was end, method  tester.onTearDown(); was called. The teat down action was locked by mentionned transactions.

I sovled described problem by changing

```
def cleanup() {
        tester.onTearDown();
    }
```

by

```
@AfterTransaction
    def cleanDatabase(){
        tester.onTearDown();
    }
```

Database cleaning operation is made after finished all transactions on given test.